# How to accomplish this MongoDB query with a large dataset from multiple different JSON files?

Tags: mongodb, search, indexing, mongodb-query

I imported 5 huge json files data from Yelp's dataset challenge into my mongodb  on Ubuntu, and several of them have the same variable names.

I imported them from the Linux command line, like so:

```
mongoimport --collection collection --file /usr/lib/yelp_academic_dataset_business.json
```

And did this for the other 4 json files, all imported the same way.

I'm mostly concerned with these variables, from these files:

business.json:

- business_id
- attributes
- type

reviews.json

- business_id
- text
- type

tips.json

- text
- type (note: every single type in this file is "tip")
- business_id

checkins.json

- time
- business_id

Here's one of the lines from business.json:

{"business_id":"mRv3Z25F56qduMKnvnCkVA","name":"Kokoya","neighborhood":"Willowdale","address":"5515 Yonge St","city":"Toronto","state":"ON","postal_code":"M2N 5S3","latitude":43.7782228,"longitude":-79.414869,"stars":3.0,"review_count":41,"is_open":1,"attributes":["Alcohol: Has_bar","Ambience: {'romantic': False, 'intimate': False, 'classy': False, 'hipster': False, 'touristy': False, 'trendy': False, 'upscale': False, 'casual': True}","BikeParking: True","BusinessAcceptsCreditCards: True","BusinessParking: {'garage': False, 'street': True, 'validated': False, 'lot': False, 'valet': False}","Caters: False","GoodForKids: False","GoodForMeal: {'dessert': False, 'latenight': True, 'lunch': False, 'dinner': False, 'breakfast': False, 'brunch': False}","HasTV: True","NoiseLevel: loud","OutdoorSeating: False","RestaurantsAttire: casual","RestaurantsDelivery: False","RestaurantsGoodForGroups: True","RestaurantsPriceRange2: 2","RestaurantsReservations: True","RestaurantsTableService: True","RestaurantsTakeOut: True","WheelchairAccessible: False","WiFi: no"],"categories":["Korean","Restaurants"],"hours":["Monday 17:0-2:0","Tuesday 17:0-2:0","Wednesday 17:0-2:0","Thursday 17:0-2:0","Friday 17:0-2:0","Saturday 17:0-2:0","Sunday 17:0-2:0"],"type":"business"}

**In short, I'm curious whether business_ids whose reviews mention "MMA" with attribute "Alcohol:Has_bar" get more checkins than businesses that do not have this attribute, but do not know how to best accomplish this**. I do not know how to differentiate text from reviews.json from tips.json, nor count the number of checkins for that business.

Ideally I could search for things like in MySQL. I don't mind having separate queries to do the work. Maybe these are separate queries:

- Number of reviews EXCLUDING tips.json WITH Alcohol:Has_bar mentioning MMA, along with total cumulative number of checkins for all business_ids associated with those reviews
- Number of reviews EXCLUDING tips.json WITHOUT Alcohol:Has_bar mentioning MMA, along with total cumulative number of checkins for all business_ids associated with those reviews

But I have no idea how to do this with command line mongo, which is the only option for this. Would we need to create an index? Could we simply do a count?

I have done the following:

```
db.collection.count({"text": /.* MMA.*/i})
```

But that just returns a raw count. I don't know how to specify only to include the text where the type is NOT equal to tips, or how to add with the Alcohol:Has_bar attribute. That seems the least of my worries when trying to figure out how to get the count of the checkins and associate the business_ids. I've been combing the MongoDB documentation and am not sure if this is possible with just counting or if we need an index, nor the correct syntax.

Edit: Here's a line from checkins.json:

```
{"time":["Tue-0:2","Wed-0:1","Wed-2:1","Mon-10:1","Fri-11:2","Fri-13:1","Sun-13:1","Thu-13:1","Sat-14:1","Sun-14:3","Thu-14:1","Tue-14:1","Wed-14:2","Sat-15:1","Sun-15:3","Thu-15:1","Tue-15:1","Fri-16:1","Sat-16:3","Sun-16:8","Wed-16:1","Sun-17:2","Thu-17:1","Sun-18:2","Thu-18:1","Sat-19:1","Sat-20:1","Sun-21:1","Thu-22:1","Tue-22:1","Mon-23:1","Sun-23:1","Tue-23:1"],"business_id":"dPxL6P_Gp74CqSPuL59Srg","type":"checkin"}
```